# SWIFT2: JSON request to array returns different values

Tags: arrays, json, tuples, swift2, alamofire

I'm using Alamofire and SwiftyJSON to pass JSON data to an array.

The first print return a correct array:

```
[(1, "Arena", "Oklahoma"), (2, "Stafium", "Berlin")]
```

But the second prints an empty array:

```
[]
```

I cannot understand why?

Here is my code. **SOLVED BY @NickCatib**

```
typealias cType = (ID: Int,Tag: String, Location: String)

var cBlue = [cType]()

var NumRows = 0

class MainViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Alamofire.request(.GET, url, parameters: ["postType": "live"]).responseJSON { (_, _, result) in

        switch result {

            case .Success(let data):

                let json = JSON(data)

                for(_,subJSON) in json["LocalInfo"] {

                    let ID = subJSON["id"].int!
                    let Tag = subJSON["Tag"].string!
                    let Location = subJSON["Location"].string!

                    let Info = (ID: ID, Tag: Tag, Location: Location)

                    cBlue.append(Info)

                }
                self.tableView.reloadData()

            case .Failure(_, let error):

                print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
        }

    }  

  }

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {    
    return 1
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   reloadUI() 
   return cBlues.count   
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell


 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellConcert",
            forIndexPath: indexPath)
        let info = cBlue[indexPath.row] as! Info
        cell.textLabel?.text = info.Tag

        return cell
    }
}
```

Is this correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acutally it is pretty simple: your second print will execute BEFORE Alamofire request is finished - `Alamofire.request` is async call that will execute later on.

You will have your information AFTER request, and if you need to set in into some UI elements you will have to call some kind of reload view or `relaodData()` if you are using `UITableView`.

You can call `reloadUI()`, your custom function, here:

```
//PRINTS THE ARRAY
reloadUI()
print(cBlue)
```

Example:

class MainViewController: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Alamofire.request(.GET, url, parameters: ["postType": "live"]).responseJSON { (_, _, result) in

        switch result {

            case .Success(let data):

                let json = JSON(data)

                for(_,subJSON) in json["LocalInfo"] {

                    let ID = subJSON["id"].int!
                    let Tag = subJSON["Tag"].string!
                    let Location = subJSON["Location"].string!

                    let Info = (ID: ID, Tag: Tag, Location: Location)

                    cBlue.append(Info)

                }


            case .Failure(_, let error):

                print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
        }
        //PRINTS THE ARRAY
        reloadUI()
        print(cBlue) 

    }  
    //PRINT [] EMPTY ARRAY
    print(cBlue)     
  }
}

func reloadUI(){
    self.tagLabel.text = (cBlue[0] as! Info).tag
    self.locationLabel.text = (cBlue[0] as! Info).location
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So if I want to use Alamofire and print the result to a Table I have to use reloadUI() ?

Comment: yeah, basicly, you will have to notify view or controller or anything else that you actually received data and that cBlue array is filled with info. For tableView, you can use reloadData() method that will repopulate your table. On the other hand, if you are using UIView, UILabels etc. you will have to create your own function - in the answer is reloadUI() that will populate your info.

Comment: Humm I dont' get it.. Can you provide an exemple?

Comment: You can call YourView.layoutSubviews() if in case you are using just UIVIewcontroller.
Whereas for UITabelviewcontroller you should call
yourtableview.reloadData();

Comment: Thank you. But reloadUI doest not exist. I have to create it?

Comment: better place for the reloadUI would be inside success block of the switch statement - and you should check if there is some actual data. reloadUI is in the code above :) and yes, you have to create it

Comment: Oh sorry it was hidden. I'll update my question. Please see if it's correct. Thank you very much!!

Comment: I just edited your question - Info is your model as far as I can see, so you cast to it from the array and use attribute. Do you get any count ?

Comment: That is the main problem. cBlue.count in the numberOfRowsInSection is always 0...

Comment: yup, addded missing part - reloadData after getting all the info you need from server.

Comment: It's working. Thank you very much... I've changed to this, is it wrong?
cell.textLabel?.text = concerts[indexPath.row].Tag

Comment: Nah, it is ok :) happy coding